# After Software Update resolutions of device decrease Android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have samsung s6 edge and yesterday i got new software update from samsung. When i installed it, my phone was xxxhdpi after update my phone is xxhdpi now. How is it possible ?

Comment: Now my android version is 5.1.1, i think that they gave this update for turkey

Answer (score 1):

In `system` folder is `build.prop` file and you can change value `ro.sf.lcd_density` and then it is possible, but I dont understant why samsung change this value.